# Off, switched off and turned off

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the sentences below?

> Make sure the power is off first.
>
> Make sure the power is switched off first.
>
> Make sure the power is turned off first.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: It won't let me edit your question without changing at least 6 characters, but you have a typo in "power os turned off".

Answer (score 2):

They all have the same meaning, though "Make sure the power is off" allows for more ways to disconnect the power than just a switch or similar control, e.g. you ideally wouldn't say "Make sure the power is switched off" if you needed to unwire a cable or unplug something.  People would understand your meaning, but it would add a small amount of confusion.

Comment: I can't see any confusion in **make sure the power is switched off**. All the (many) homes I've lived in have a power distribution / switch board with a series of switches, including a mains switch that cuts the power. We are all accustomed to turning/switching lights and appliances on and off.

Comment: @RonaldSole Yes, but in the cases where you don't have a switch available..

Comment: Okay, fair enough!

Comment: Under most circumstances I agree it would make no difference.